# Contact form with html and php

Tags: php, html, contact-form

```
Hi im a newbie so i tried to use some source code to create a contact form for my website it does not work so i need help here is my code: 

HTML

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="row contact-form">
            <form id="contact-form" action="php/mail.php">
                <fieldset class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="col-md-12">
                    <textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send Message" id="submit" class="button">
                </fieldset>
            </form> 
        </div> <!-- /.contact-form -->   
    </div> <!-- /.col-md-6 -->

PHP

    <?php
    include 'functions.php';

    if (!empty($_POST)){
        $data['success'] = true;
        $_POST = multiDimensionalArrayMap('cleanEvilTags', $_POST);
        $_POST = multiDimensionalArrayMap('cleanData', $_POST);

        // your email adress 
        $emailTo ="brinny@abvconstruction.co.za"; // "yourmail@yoursite.com";

        // from email adress
        $emailFrom ="contact@yoursite.com"; // "contact@yoursite.com";

        // email subject
        $emailSubject = "Mail from Web Contact Form ";

        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $comment = $_POST["comment"];
        if($name == "")
            $data['success'] = false;

        if (!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", $email)) 
            $data['success'] = false;


        if($comment == "")
            $data['success'] = false;

        if($data['success'] == true){
            $message = "NAME: $name<br>
                EMAIL: $email<br>
                COMMENT: $comment";

            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "From: <$emailFrom>" . "\r\n";
            mail($emailTo, $emailSubject, $message, $headers);

            $data['success'] = true;
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }

Thank you. I changed the code to this :

<?php

include 'functions.php';

if (!empty($_POST)){

  $data['success'] = true;


  //your email adress 
  $emailTo ="brinny@abvconstruction.co.za"; //"yourmail@yoursite.com";

  //from email adress
  $emailFrom = $_POST["email"]; //"contact@yoursite.com";

  //email subject
  $emailSubject = $_POST["subject"];

  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $comments = $_POST["comments"];
  if($name == "")
   $data['success'] = false;

 if (!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", $email)) 
   $data['success'] = false;


 if($comments == "")
   $data['success'] = false;

 if($data['success'] == true){

  $message = "NAME: $name<br>
  EMAIL: $email<br>
  COMMENT: $comments";


  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n"; 
  $headers .= "From: <$emailFrom>" . "\r\n";
  mail($emailTo, $emailSubject, $message, $headers);

  $data['success'] = true;
  echo json_encode($data);
}`enter code here`
}
```

I would also like to know if i should use a php_redirect to get the browser to open the html file not the php file

The website is abvconstruction.co.za. If any one can check what is the error on my code

Comment: Why it does not work? Does it thrown an error? If so, what error?

Comment: When i click the submit butoon it opens the php file

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to add `method="post"` to your `<form>`, otherwise it's sending the data with GET.

Also remove these lines, which clear the POST data:

```
$_POST  = multiDimensionalArrayMap('cleanEvilTags', $_POST);
$_POST  = multiDimensionalArrayMap('cleanData', $_POST);
```

Comment: I did add the post method to the form and removed these lines:

$_POST  = multiDimensionalArrayMap('cleanEvilTags', $_POST);
$_POST  = multiDimensionalArrayMap('cleanData', $_POST);

But once i click the submit button it opens the php file

I need to know if theres anything wrong with my php file or the contact form

Comment: I saw some mistakes: first, you've got a field `subject` which you don't use in your php-code, this field is useless ... second, your `comments`-field is called `comments`, but you're using `$_POST['comment']` in your php code, change this to `$_POST['comments']`. That's all I see so far

Answer (score 1):

first remove these line, they clear the post values

```
  $_POST  = multiDimensionalArrayMap('cleanEvilTags', $_POST);
  $_POST  = multiDimensionalArrayMap('cleanData', $_POST);
```